Bind to imported $state in svelte5 (error "constant_binding")
// states.svelte.js
export let name = $state("John"); // a state to be shared by multiple components

<!-- Component.svelte -->
<script>
  import { name } from "./states.svelte.js";
</script>

<p>Hello, my name is <input type="text" bind:value={name} /></p>

REPL
When migrating to svelte5, I try to replace a writable store with a $state, but get error Cannot bind to import (https://svelte.dev/e/constant_binding).
What's the correct way to do it?

I can only give the solution but not the why: when using runes for shared state they should be in an object:
export const user = $state({
  name: 'John',
});

P.S. As @brunnerh showed in his answer, if an object name like userState doesn't make sense the convention is: const name = $state({ current: "John" })
and:
<script>
  import { userState } from "./states.svelte.js";
</script>

<p>Hello, my name is <input type="text" bind:value={user.name} /></p>

Unfortunately the docs aren't clear that this is needed and why. I would also be interested to understand if it's a technical or philosophical imposition. I know that observables don't work well with primitive values as they're copied by value, so it could be technical.

It's a combination of how the language works and how runes work. Imports cannot be re-assigned due to how JS is specified but even if that were possible, the reactivity would not be transferred because the value is a primitive here.

You cannot modify primitives and imports are treated as constants, so the value needs to be wrapped, then you can modify the property holding the value, e.g.
export let name = $state({ current: "John" });

Then bind to name.current.
(For reference see also the svelte/reactivity/window module, it exposes various primitives, each in an object with a current property to preserve reactivity.)
